# tfs tasks\bugs edited by me

Tags: tfs

Once I've finish working on an item and it is assigned to someone else, it exits my queries scope and I can't find it anymore. Sometimes I just need to make a quick look up on items that went through me and recognize an old bug by description or date.

Is there a query like that by default in TFS2010 ?
How else can I search bugs that have me in their history flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. There is an "Was Ever" operator for the "Assigned To" field. This will allow you to query any work item that was ever assigned to you. The same operator exists on the "Changed By" field.